# Closed-form of an integral involving a Jacobi theta function, $ \int_0^{t} \theta_3(e^{-\pi^2 (t-\tau)}) \, \theta_2(e^{-\pi^2 \tau}) \ d\tau =1$

Tags: theta-functions

Numerical calculation of a Duhamel-Integral coming up considering a unsteady state diffusion in a thin film electrode with zero initial concentration leads to the following strange identity:

$$ \int_0^t \theta_3(e^{-\pi^2 (t-\tau)}) \, \theta_2(e^{-\pi^2 \tau}) \ d \tau = 1$$

Question: Has anybody an idea to prove that.

Comment: Sorry, this was my first question here, the formula in the body is the correct one!

Comment: \pi is just the number.

Comment: Let me explain a little bit more.

Comment: The integral may be proven by the convolution theorem.

Comment: H(s)=F(s) G(s), now, I found a physical problem showing that $H(s)=Coth(\sqrt{s})/\sqrt{s} Tanh(\sqrt{s})/\sqrt{s}=1/s$. The Laplace-Transform of the first term is the first term of the integral in the body $\theta_3$ the second term is the second term of the integral in the body $\theta_2$

Comment: If you already have a method of proof, then what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I try to understand, whether this identity is trivial or useful for other problems. The aim is to use a Laplace transform on a geometrical sequence $Sum (Coth(\sqrt{s}/\sqrt(s)))^k to solve the diffusion equation of a  spherical electrode particle with a new method, never published.