# Proof of an identity containing the Riemann zeta-function with the help of the Zeta functional equation

Tags: calculus, complex-integration, riemann-zeta, mellin-transform

**Problem statement:**
While I was writing another question and explaining, what I have already tried so far, I came across the following identity:
$$\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1-2\,s}{2}\right)\,\zeta\left(-2\,s\right)}{\sqrt{\pi}\,s}=-\frac{\pi^{-2s}\,\sec\left(\pi\,s\right)\,\zeta\left(1+2\,s\right)}{\Gamma\left(1-s\right)}$$
$\zeta\left(s\right)$ is the Riemann zeta-function and $\Gamma\left(s\right)$ the gamma function. I assume, that this identity can be proven by the [Zeta functional equation](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Functional_Equation_for_Riemann_Zeta_Function), but I haven't figured out how to show that.

**EDIT 29.05.21**

Inspired by a recent comment of @StevenClark and @metamorphy I finally managed to derivate the reflection functional equation of the Riemann zeta-function starting from the identity above. For the proof only the substituion $s\to -\frac{s}{2}$ is needed.

**Attempt at an alternative proof:**
I found the following alternative proof, which is very interesting. We rewrite the identity in the form:
$$-2\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1-2\,s}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi}\,s}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^{-2s}=\frac{4}{\pi^{\frac{3}{2}}}\frac{\pi^{\frac{3}{2}-2s}\sec\left(\pi\,s\right)}{2\,\Gamma\left(1-s\right)}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^{1+2s}$$
Using the [Mellin inverse transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform) on both sides leads to the interesting identity:
$$1+2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{k}{\sqrt{z}}\right)=\frac{2\sqrt{z}}{\sqrt{\pi}}+\frac{4}{\pi^{\frac{3}{2}}}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\text{DawsonF}[k\,\pi\,\sqrt{z}]}{k}$$
$\text{DawsonF}\left(z\right)$ is Dawson's integral and $\text{erfc}\left(z\right)$ is the complementary error function. The left- and right-hand side may be written by its integral representation:
$$\mathcal{G}\left(z\right)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\vartheta_{3}\left(0,\exp\left(-\frac{1}{z~\tau}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{\tau\,\left(1-\tau\right)}}=\sqrt{\frac{z}{\pi}}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\vartheta_{3}\left(0,\exp\left(-\pi^{2}\,z~\tau\right)\right)}{\sqrt{\left(1-\tau\right)}}$$
The equality may be proved by the Jacobi theta functional equation [Peter Woit,p.4](http://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Ewoit/fourier-analysis/theta-zeta.pdf). The new function $\mathcal{G}\left(z\right)$
, will be subject of a future post of us.
It has the known property of the theta function $\vartheta_{3}$, too: the functional equation.
The proof of this transformation formula is then based on a result from
theory of Fourier series called [Poisson Summation Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula).  For this the Fourier transform has to be applied, resulting in the last identity.

Comment: Isn't it just a substitution $s\mapsto 2s+1$ (in the functional equation)? [+ reflection formula for $\Gamma$]

Comment: @metamorphy: Please descibe more detailed, we might talk about different forms of the Zeta functional equation,

Comment: @metamorphy Or try substituting $s\to-s/2$ which leads to $\zeta(s)$ on the left and $\zeta(1-s)$ on the right?

Comment: @StevenClark: Thank you ! I finally understand the proof. I only have to substitute $s\to -\frac{s}{2}$.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: It's an interesting identity which I believe is valid for $Re(z)>0$. There seems to be a striking resemblance to my formulas $\text{erfc}\left(\sqrt{z}\right)=\underset{N,f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(2\,\pi^{-3/2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\mu(n)\sum\limits_{k=1}^{f\,n}\frac{F\left(\frac{k\,\pi}{n \sqrt{z}}\right)}{k}\right)$ and $F\left(\sqrt{z}\right)=\underset{N,f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\pi^{3/2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{f\,n}\text{erfc}\left(\frac{k\,\pi}{n \sqrt{z}}\right)\right)$ both of which I believe are also valid for $\Re(z)>0$.

Comment: Both of my formulas must be evaluated at $M(N)=0$ where $M(N)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\mu(n)$ is the Mertens function. My formulas seem much more sensitive to the magnitude of $N$ than they are to the magnitude of $f$ which is assumed to be a positive integer.

Comment: That's very interesting: First I wanted to Iook for any special value - similar to [Istvan
 Mezo] (https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2013-141-07/S0002-9939-2013-11576-5/home.html) - for the new functions

Comment: $\mathcal{H}\left(z\right)=1+2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{k}erfc\left(\frac{k}{\sqrt{z}}\right)\;and\;\mathcal{G}\left(z\right)=1+2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}erfc\left(\frac{k}{\sqrt{z}}\right)$ defined by their integral representations: $\mathcal{H}\left(z\right)=\sqrt{\frac{z}{\pi}}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\vartheta_{2}\left(0,\exp\left(-\pi^{2}z~\tau\right)\right)}{\sqrt{\left(1-\tau\right)}}\;and\;\mathcal{G}\left(z\right)=\sqrt{\frac{z}{\pi}}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\vartheta_{3}\left(0,\exp\left(-\pi^{2}z~\tau\right)\right)}{\sqrt{\left(1-\tau\right)}}$

Comment: These functions occur by the treatment of the Duhamel-Integral [stocha] (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2082444/closed-form-of-an-integral-involving-a-jacobi-theta-function-int-0t-thet) $\int_{0}^{t}\vartheta_{3}\left(0,\exp\left(-\pi^{2}~\left(t-\tau\right)\right)\right)\vartheta_{2}\left(0,\exp\left(-\pi^{2}~\tau\right)\right)\ d\tau=1$ The new functions, I study have the known property of the theta function,
 too: the functional equation:

Comment: $1+2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}erfc\left(\frac{k}{\sqrt{z}}\right)=\frac{2\sqrt{z}}{\sqrt{\pi}}+\frac{4}{\pi^{\frac{3}{2}}}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\text{DawsonF}[k\,\pi\sqrt{z}]}{k}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124862/discussion-between-stocha-and-steven-clark).

Comment: Here are a couple of related formulas which I believe are both valid for $\Re(z)>0$: $\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{z}\right)=\underset{N,f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{f\,n}\Gamma\left(0,\frac{k^2 \pi^2}{n^2 z}\right)\right)$ and $e^{-z}=\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{z}} \sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\vartheta_3\left(0,e^{-\frac{\pi ^2}{n^2 z}}\right)\right)$. I posted here since chat doesn't render MathJax.

Comment: When evaluating these formulas at a finite evaluation limit, $N$ must again be selected such that $M(N)=0$. It's possible to evaluate these formulas at arbitrarily large magnitudes of $N$ since the Mertens function has an infinite number of zeros.

Comment: I have another remarkable formula for the dawson function $F[y]$, that could be interesting to you. $\underset{t\rightarrow \infty }{\lim }\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{k^{4\,t+1}}\left( \text{F}[k~\sqrt{y}]\right) =\text{F}[\sqrt{y}]$ I already proofed this formula.

Comment: @Gary: Thank you!